# 'DataTable' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable'

Tags: c#, .net

My code is working fine until I changed its location.
Actually use of full name like **System.Data.DataTable** will resolve the problem but I  need to do it 'n' number of pages. Can anyone suggest me smarter way to resolve this in all pages.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code but you could always try just renaming it like so: `using DataTable = System.Data.DataTable;`

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + F and then pressing the small arrow on the left, that way you can replace the string in the entire project

Comment: Are you using both the namespaces on same pages?

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because your are using both of the namepsaces:

```
using System.Data.DataTable;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable;
```

Both have a class object called `DataTable`.

When you call, for example:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
```

the compiler can't distinguish the object of `DataTable` you are trying to call/use -

the one under `System.Data.DataTable` or the one under `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable` and thus, the error too.
**The compiler is asking you the specify in which namespace the object is located because it cannot determine by himself**

Answer (score 1):

`System.Data` and `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` have a class named `DataTable`. So you must explicitly specify in your code when you want to use `DataTable` of `System.Data` or `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

Selon your situation, I suppose that `DataTable` of `System.Data` is more used than other. Then you can alias the namespace `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and fix the code to use this alias when you want to use `DataTable` of `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`. This reduces the fixing of code.

```
using DataTableWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

var dataTable = new DataTableWord.DataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable or you can  set the using statement specifically.

```
using System.Data.DataTable
```

And remove any usings pointing to the reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You Remove reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable or set the using statement specifically.

using System.Data.DataTable

And remove any usings pointing to the reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DataTable.